# Searching data in database using JSP

Tags: java, jsp

What is the problem with the following code? I want to search data in the database using the following JSP code.

search.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<html>
<form>
<table>
<%
String value=request.getParameter("id");
int v=Integer.parseInt(value);
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee ","root", "root");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from test where id="+v+"");
if(rs.next()){ 
    %>
<tr><td>Name: </td><td<input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("name")%>" > </td></tr>
<tr><td>Address: </td><td<input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("address")%>" > </td></tr>
<tr><td>Contact No: </td><td<input type="text" value="<%=rs.getInt("contactNo")%>" > </td></tr>
<tr><td>Email: </td><td<input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("email")%>" > </td></tr>
      <%
}
%>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: The exception you get tells you w

Comment: 14:     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); in this line it shows the error. Please explain i am the new for jsp. Thanks

Comment: BTW there is a space after `employee` and you do not call `rs.close();conn.close();`` nor exception handling. Run the code first in an IDE as tiny java application.

Comment: @user274910 possible cause that there's no mysql jdbc driver in your classpath, make sure you have added this driver to your project.

Comment: @user274910 and if you have the JDBC driver on you path you do not need the `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` anymore. This is a relict from old Java version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the select query your query is wrong try:

```
"select * from test where id='"+v+"'"
```

One simple example :

```
<%
  String value=request.getParameter("student_id");;
  int v=Integer.parseInt(value);
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root", "welcome");
  Statement st=conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from student where student_id='"+v+"'");
  if(rs.next()){
      %>
  <tr><td>Name: </td><td><input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("student_name")%>"/> </td></tr>
        <%
  }
  %>
```

Comment: Thanks i have succeeded

Comment: if it worked please accept it as your answer clicking the arrow sign at left side of the answer and you can vote it up. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I never suggest you to use **Scriplet** in JSP instead use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) that is more easy to use and **less error prone**.

You can achieve it using [JSTL SQL Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html).

Use [JSTL Core c:forEach, c:forTokens Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm) that is s a good alternative to embedding a Java `for`, `while`, or `do-while loop` via a Scriptlet.

---

Sample code: (*change it as per your need*)

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<sql:query dataSource="${dataSource}"
    sql="select name,address,contactNo,email from test where id=?" var="result">
    <sql:param value="${param.id}"></sql:param>
</sql:query>

<table border="1">
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="${row.name}"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="${row.address}"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="${row.contactNo}"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="${row.email}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Find complete sample code here on [JSTL SQL Tag](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_sql_update_tag.htm).

Answer (score 0):

1-->Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee","root", "root");

in your code there is a space after tha database name

2-->
Name: " > 
Address: " > 
Contact No: " > 
Email: " >

check your Name:

i think while loop is better than if in this case